# Failed to parse int 3 in base 3

Tags: java, radix

Strangest thing. I have this line

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("3",3);
```

But everytime i run it, i get a NumberFormatException.forInputString. Why? this is a simple base conversion. What is so special about the int 3 that breaks the conversion?

Comment: In case of base 3 the highest digit is 2, not 3. And it's a String, has to be quoted even when it contains a number

Comment: Because there is 0,1,2 in base 3?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, the int 3 is in string

Comment: Why the downvotes and "close"? It's a reasonable question and ignorance is not a crime - it's why SO exists. If we knew all the answers and never made mistakes ... But this seems to be common now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to parse base-10 to base-n `String` you can use something like :

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(3, 2)); // print 11 -> String data type
```

Code above is to parse `3` in base 10 (integer) as binary (base-2) `String`.

Following code should parse base-2 `String` as base-10 integer value :

```
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt("11", 2)); // print 3 -> base-10 integer
```

Code above is to parse `11` binary to base-10 integer. Your code have error with this String format, for base-3 the string only consist `0`, `1`, `2`.

Please note the difference how to use both method.

Answer (score 6):

1. [`parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) expects a String as the first argument.
2. In base 3 there is no digit "3". Just "0" to "2". A decimal "3" is represented by "10" in base 3.

Answer (score 2):

[`Integer.parseInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) expects a string to parse, not an integer. You want

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("3", 3);
```

You'll also run into the problem that 3 is not a digit in base three. As per the documentation, that will still throw a NumberFormatException.

> Any character of the string is not a digit of the specified radix

Comment: `3` is no valid base-3 number, made the same mistake in my answer ;)

Comment: This still throws the `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Fixed - forgot it needed to be parseable in that radix.

Comment: I'm i using the wrong approach to convert to the next base? My string values are all in decimal. I thought that JAVA would convert first into the specified radix then parse the result appropriately.

Comment: @TheJackal if you just want to display it in base 3, use [`Integer.toString(i, 3)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

`3` must be a numeric `String` to parse into an `int` rather than an `int` literal:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("2", 3);
```

Furthermore, base-3 numbers cannot contain a `3` digit, as there's only `0`, `1` and `2` available. Therefore I used `2` in the example code above.

Comment: Except that `3` isn't a valid base 3 digit anyway.

Answer (score 0):

3 simply does not exist as a digit in base 3...
0, 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 100

Comment: so 2 doesn't exist in base 2, and 10 doesn't exist in base 10?

Comment: @Pshemo True, it'd be `10` instead (additional digit).

Comment: "It was just a dream, Bender. There's no such thing as two."

Comment: @MatthiasMeid so it exists, but is written using two digits (other story is that there is no symbol like 3 in base 3 system)

Comment: @Pshemo Strictly speaking it might exist, depending on whether you're looking at `3` in this post as a number or as a digit (suggested an edit to the post to point it out clearly)...

Comment: @MatthiasMeid OP was using 3 as number so why I (and author of this answer) should not? BTW only after your update this answer have sense.

Comment: @Pshemo I didn't intend to say you're wrong. IMHO the answer just wasn't fully non-ambiguous, so I think it's good we discussed the point and edited it. Again, I certainly agree there is such a number as *base-10 three* in base-3.

Answer (score 0):

- `Integer.parseInt` takes String as a signed decimal integer, and that integer must be less than and not equal radix value (base).

  ```
  Integer.parseInt("X",x); //X mustn't contain x.
  ```